# Eigenvalues of block-hermitian matrices with zero diagonal blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-theory, block-matrices

I have a matrix of the form

$$D = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & C \\ C^{\dagger} & 0 \end{array} \right)$$

where $C$ is not necessarily hermitian. In general, can we say anything about the eigenvalues of $D$ in terms of $C$? In particular, I'm interested in the case where every eigenvalue of $C$ has algebraic multiplicity 2, and what that implies about the multiplicities of the eigenvalues of $D$.

Comment: If you square it, the resulting matrix has nonnegative eigenvalues of $CC*$ with multiplicity multiplied by two (since $CC^*$ and $C^*C$ are unitarily conjugate). The corresponding eigenvalues of $D$ are the square roots. This has relatively little to do with the eigenvalues of $C$ itself, rather the singular values. I'm sure you can figure out the details---or was this part of an exercise? Most of the time, when $\dagger$ for conjugacy transpose, it's an exercise.

Comment: As @David said, it is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Calculating_the_SVD) that the eigenvectors of $D$ are precisely the singular pairs of $C$.